# Sum values between empty cells in a huge table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, bigdata, worksheet-function

I have an Excel table with ~800,000 lines, made in Linux and containing data about processes and CPU load. I would like to summarize the results. For example:

Let`s imagine we have the following output in column D:

```
empty cell
0
39
39
2
3
empty cell
```

Can Excel summarize the values between the empty cells / is there a function for it?

If yes, is it possible to run this for all the ~800,000 lines?

Comment: What type of summary?  The average?  The total?

Comment: The total number of each series between empty cells. So in other definition, empty cell would be the border of the series.

Comment: `Average function Remarks` : If a range or cell reference argument contains text, logical values, or empty cells, those values are ignored; however, cells with the value zero are included. Read more [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/average-function-HP010062482.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I want to summarize the values of every series between 2 empty cells. So not for the whole table but for the series between empty cells. So is there a possibility to do something like this :

while x < 8 000 000
do find series of values between empty cells
summarize the serioes between empty cells

Comment: A VBA macro could be written to read the values and write to external seq. file. No function exists in excel for that that I know of.

Comment: Sorry, I found that I have 800 000 lines.

Comment: Hi, so the case is the following:

I have a log with ~800 lines and in one column I have these values:

Let`s say this is group1:
0
39
39
2
3

Some rows later (empty in that column):

Lets say group2:

0
100
256
2
3

So, I have it in ~2600 times during ~800000 lines and it `d be very good if I could have the sums for group1, group2 ...

As Ennad Kareem wrote it should be good to know if we can use empty cells as group separators.

Comment: @pnuts, thanks your are correct, I need to find out how would subtotals work based on a blank line as a group separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If to avoid VBA, Subtotal might just work for 800,000 rows. At the moment 1 in 6 is blank so the end result might be 800,000 + 800,000/6 (for the subtotal rows themselves) = just under the current Excel limit.

Add a helper column (say B) with a formula that returns blank only if A2 (assumes your column is labelled) is blank (assumes your data is in ColumnA), say `=IF(A2="","","x")` and copy down to ~row800000.

Subtotal ColumnA:B for each change in B with your choice of function to Add subtotal to: ColumnA.

To Subtotal, select the data column and the grouping column, got to Data > Outline - Subtotal and At each change in: put the column with values, Use function: as appropriate, check or uncheck options to suit and OK.

Cross your fingers and hope the sheet is large enough!

Comment: That is it! Well done.

Comment: Hi pnuts!

Thanks for Answer, but could you please write how do you mean the subtotal part of it?

So now, in B I have the x values where it is needed, could you please write an example for using subtotal? Tahnks in advance!

Comment: @pnuts The job is ongoing, for at least 40 minutes and still not stopped. I`ll let you know once I`ve received results.

Comment: Hi!After 90 minutes, the computing stopped with no result, so the table is too big.

Anyway thank you very much for your sulution, since it can be very useful for normal-sized excel tables.